# Combined plot of ggplot2 (Not in a single Plot), using par() or layout() function?

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2, par

I've been thinking of using par() or layout() functions for combining ggplots. Will it be possible to use those functions?

Say I want to plot ggplot for scatterplot and ggplot for histogram. And I want to combine the two plots (NOT IN A SINGLE PLOT). Is it applicable?

I tried it with simple plotting in R, without using the ggplot functions. And it works actually.

Here's a sample from Quick-R, Link: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

```
# 4 figures arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")

# One figure in row 1 and two figures in row 2
attach(mtcars)
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
hist(wt)
hist(mpg)
hist(disp)
```

But when I try to use ggplot, and combine the plot, I don't get an output.

Comment: ggplot2 is not a base graphics so you cannot combine ggplot2 and layout or par(mfrow). you need to use, e.g., plot.arrange etc in gridExtra. Or, you can play with viewport in grid system.

Comment: Since you asked for something like `layout()`, you probably want something like `grid.arrange()` (as kohske mentioned). [This linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993722/creating-arbitrary-panes-in-ggplot2/7996205#7996205) (and Ben Bolker's answer in particular) will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)


vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)


plot1 <- qplot(mtcars,x=wt,y=mpg,geom="point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot2 <- qplot(mtcars,x=wt,y=disp,geom="point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
plot3 <- qplot(wt,data=mtcars)
plot4 <- qplot(wt,mpg,data=mtcars,geom="boxplot")
plot5 <- qplot(wt,data=mtcars)
plot6 <- qplot(mpg,data=mtcars)
plot7 <- qplot(disp,data=mtcars)

# 4 figures arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(plot1, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(plot2, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
print(plot3, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(plot4, vp = vplayout(2, 2))


# One figure in row 1 and two figures in row 2
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(plot5, vp = vplayout(1, 1:2))
print(plot6, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(plot7, vp = vplayout(2, 2))
```

Comment: To Maiasaura,

Thank you for the script/code.

But I got an error when I print plot1 and plot2, that says "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'wt' not found".

However, I fixed it by rearranging your argument in plot1 and plot2.

    plot1 <- qplot(x=wt,y=mpg,data = mtcars,geom = "point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
and    plot2 <- qplot(x=wt,y=disp, data = mtcars,geom="point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")

Thank you again for a quick response.

Comment: @Maiasaura Thanks for the great answers. How can I add a title to the entire grid as a main title. I saw grid.text option but in a 2 by 4 grid it doesn't come nicely at the top and the middle.

Comment: This solution should be marked as being obsolete as the grid packages was removed from CRAN recently.

Answer (score 13):

A utility I think deserves more attention for this is the `layOut` formerly of th `wq` package (note the capital "O"). It's since been removed from the `wq` package, so I've put the code below and renamed it `lay_out` to match typical ggplot style. It is like `base::layout` in that the plots can be of varying sizes, laid out in rows and columns. Each argument to `lay_out` is a 3-element list consisting of the plot, the row indices in which to plot it, and the column indices in which to plot it.

For example, using @Paul McMurdie's plots,

```
lay_out(list(plot1, 1, 1),
        list(plot2, 1, 2),
        list(plot3, 2, 1),
        list(plot4, 2, 2),
        list(plot5, 3, 1:2),
        list(plot6, 4, 1:2),
        list(plot7, 1:2, 3))
```

[image]

```
lay_out = function(...) {    
    x <- list(...)
    n <- max(sapply(x, function(x) max(x[[2]])))
    p <- max(sapply(x, function(x) max(x[[3]])))
    grid::pushViewport(grid::viewport(layout = grid::grid.layout(n, p)))    

    for (i in seq_len(length(x))) {
        print(x[[i]][[1]], vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = x[[i]][[2]], 
            layout.pos.col = x[[i]][[3]]))
    }
}
```

(Code sourced from a prior version of the `wq` package, from the [commit history on the unofficial Github CRAN mirror](https://github.com/cran/wq/blob/8223da687d8daff2ad612f9a07926f412a08ba82/R/layOut.R).)

Comment: I really love this solutions. grid.arrange does not offer the nice placement of the plots.

Comment: @Grego.  The package wq (water quality) does not seem to have the function layOut() any more.  Is that correct?

Comment: @lawyeR apparently so. I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: How do I install the necessary package?  I tried `install.packages("layOut")` and `install.packages("lay_out")` to no avail.

Comment: Ah sorry got it from your Github link, I didn't realise you'd linked to the function source :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer involving `grid.layout` works, I've used it, and I up-voted it. However, I usually find this solution much too tedious and error-prone, and I suspect most ggplot2 enthusiasts that do this regularly have wrapped this up in a function. I have found several such wrapping functions in previous searches, but my current workhorse solution is in a [grid addon package called `gridExtra`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html). It has useful arguments, but the default rows/columns setup is often what you wanted in the first place:

```
library("ggplot2")
# Generate list of arbitrary ggplots
plot1 <- qplot(data = mtcars, x=wt, y=mpg, geom="point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot2 <- qplot(data = mtcars, x=wt, y=disp, geom="point",main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
plot3 <- qplot(wt,data=mtcars)
plot4 <- qplot(wt,mpg,data=mtcars,geom="boxplot")
plot5 <- qplot(wt,data=mtcars)
plot6 <- qplot(mpg,data=mtcars)
plot7 <- qplot(disp,data=mtcars)
# You might have produced myPlotList using instead lapply, mc.lapply, plyr::dlply, etc 
myPlotList = list(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, plot5, plot6, plot7)
library("gridExtra")
do.call(grid.arrange,  myPlotList)
```

Notice how the actual "combine my plots into one graphic" code was one line (after loading gridExtra). You might argue that putting the plots into a list was an extra line, but actually I could have alternatively used

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, plot5, plot6, plot7)
```

For small numbers of ggplots this might be preferable. However, for `n_plots > 4` you will begin to resent having to name and type them all.

Comment: if you wanted two columns, for example, resulting from grid.arrange, what would the final line contain?  I have tried variations on args = list( ncol = 2)

Comment: Here's the one-liner: `do.call(grid.arrange,  c(myPlotList, list(ncol = 2)))`