# ggplot2: Define plot layout with grid.arrange() as argument of do.call()

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to obtained an unbalanced grid of plots such as

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(value1 = rnorm(200),
                 value2 = rnorm(200),
                 value3 = rnorm(200),
                 value4 = rnorm(200))

p1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=value1))
p2 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=value2))
p3 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=value3))
p4 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=value4))

grid.arrange(p1, arrangeGrob(p2,p3,p4, ncol=3), heights=c(2.5/4, 1.5/4), ncol=1)
```

[image]

but using a function

```
myplot <- function(i){
  p <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes_string(x=i))
  return(p)
}
```

and an `lapply` call

```
p <- lapply(c("value1","value2","value3","value4"), myplot)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(p))
```

In this case `grid.arrange` distribute the plots in a 2 by 2 matrix. But I want to obtain an unbalanced layout as  with

```
grid.arrange(p1, arrangeGrob(p2,p3,p4, ncol=3), heights=c(2.5/4, 1.5/4), ncol=1)
```

Comment: My question is different because in my case the plots are unbalanced. I can't simply pass a list to do.call because I want different heights for different plots (see figure)

Comment: So, you want to define a layout. Please adjust your question title and body accordingly.

Comment: Did some edits. Not sure whether it's OK, not sure exactly what you mean by layout.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18428858/1412059

Comment: Nested `grid.arrange`/`arrangeGrob` calls define a layout. You can't achieve that by just passing `heights`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can now do,

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,1,1),c(2,3,4)))
```