# Control layout when displaying a series of ggplot plots stored in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I would like to control the layout when plotting a series of ggplots
that I have stored in a list (generated automatically elsewhere).

I can plot series of plots as below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, (aes(x=mpg, fill=as.factor(1)))) + geom_density() +  
                      scale_fill_manual(values="red") 
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, (aes(x=mpg, fill=as.factor(1)))) + geom_density() +  
                      scale_fill_manual(values="orange") 
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, (aes(x=mpg, fill=as.factor(1)))) + geom_density() +  
                      scale_fill_manual(values="yellow") 
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, (aes(x=mpg, fill=as.factor(1)))) + geom_density() +  
                      scale_fill_manual(values="green") 
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

[image: grid.arrange basic]

I can then change their layout, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299529/ggplot2-define-plot-layout-with-grid-arrange-as-argument-of-do-call).

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))
```

[image: grid.arrange new layout]

I can also plot a series of plots if they are stored in a list, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706753/how-do-i-arrange-a-variable-list-of-plots-using-grid-arrange).

```
myplotslist <- list(p1, p2, p3, p4)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(myplotslist, ncol=2))
```

[image]

But if I try to change the layout using layout_matrix, I get an error (and some warnings).

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(myplotslist, ncol=2, layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))))

Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
2: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
3: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
4: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
```

I have tried coercing the plot objects to grobs, but encounter the same error.

```
myplotslist2 <- list(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), ggplotGrob(p3), ggplotGrob(p4))
```

I am using R 3.2.1, ggplot2 2.0.0, grid 3.2.1, and gridExtra 2.0.0, and would be extremely grateful for suggestions.

Comment: `grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2, layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to the function you pass to `do.call` are really supposed to be a list. From `?do.call`:

> `args`     a *list* of arguments to the function call. The `names` attribute of
>   `args` gives the argument names.

The errors are telling you that your other arguments are getting passed to the `grobs` argument of `grid.arrange`. To stop that, put it in a list (`c` flattens too much here) and specify the `grobs` argument name for `myplotslist`:

```
do.call(grid.arrange, list(grobs = myplotslist, ncol=2, layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))))
```

...or you can ditch `do.call` entirely (h/t Baptiste):

```
grid.arrange(grobs = myplotslist, ncol=2, layout_matrix=cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure why but this seems to work:

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(myplotslist, ncol=2, layout_matrix=list(cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))))
```

Comment: `c` flattens the matrix. See the difference between `c(cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))` (`1 2 3 4`) and `list(cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)))` (a matrix in a list).