# Fill ggplot facet panel with white space in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299529/ggplot2-define-plot-layout-with-grid-arrange-as-argument-of-do-call) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681145/how-can-i-arrange-an-arbitrary-number-of-ggplots-using-grid-arrange) on how to arrange ggplots in a grid using loops. However, I can't piece together what I'm after.

I want to plot an arbitrary number of equally sized graphs in a loop. Crucially, I want to use `facet_wrap` AND pre split the data into groups (explained why below). Here is an example:

```
df <- mtcars
df$car <- rownames(df)

ucar <- unique(df$car)

# Split data into groups of n (6's here)
split6s <- split(ucar, ceiling(seq_along(ucar)/6))

p <- list()

# For each group of 6, plot something (mpg vs wt) faceted by group (car)
for(i in 1 :length(split6s)){
  # Subset for group
  temp <- subset(df, car %in% split6s[[i]])    

    # Save plot forcing facet with 1 row
    p[[i]] <- ggplot(temp, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + 
                facet_wrap(~car, nrow = 1)
}

p[[5]]
```

[image]

```
p[[6]]
```

[image]

Desired `p[[6]]`

[image]

I want to do this so that I can standardize the size of some graphs in `rmarkdown` but use facets instead of just grobbing individual plots together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the solution that you are looking for.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- mtcars
df$car <- rownames(df)
ucar <- unique(df$car)
split6s <- split(ucar, ceiling(seq_along(ucar)/6))

p <- list()
for(i in 1 :length(split6s)){
  temp <- subset(df, car %in% split6s[[i]])    
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(temp, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + 
                facet_wrap(~car, nrow = 1)
}

g5 <- ggplotGrob(p[[5]])
g6 <- ggplotGrob(p[[6]])

# Delete left panels     
for (k in c(4:7, 16:19, 34:37)) {
  g5$grobs[[k]] <- nullGrob()
}
# Copy Maserati and Volvo panels
g5$grobs[[2]] <-  g6$grobs[[2]]
g5$grobs[[3]] <-  g6$grobs[[3]]
g5$grobs[[14]] <-  g6$grobs[[6]]
g5$grobs[[15]] <-  g6$grobs[[7]]
g5$grobs[[32]] <-  g6$grobs[[12]]
g5$grobs[[33]] <-  g6$grobs[[13]]
# Move left x-axis label
g5$grobs[[39]]$children[[1]]$x <- unit(1/6, "npc")

grid.draw(g5)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that gives me a great start. I need to play with the numbers so that it automatically knows how many panels to remove. In my actual code, the number of panels in the last plot will change depending on my data.