# In r, how to control proportion of plots versus x-axis in a combined plot (plot_grid)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have two plots, which have good proportions of the plot itself and the text of the x-axis.
[enter image description here][1] and [enter image description here][2]

However, when I combine them into one plot using plot_grid function, the text of the x-axis take a much larger proportion of the combined plot. [enter image description here][3]

How can I combine the plots while saving or controlling the proportions of the x-axis versus the plots themselves WITHOUT making the text smaller?

Here is my code:

````
  ggplot(variance_birds, aes(x=reorder(Species, order), precentage)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type), colour = 'black', size = 3, stroke = 1.5) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, angle = 70, colour = 'black', 
                                   vjust = 0.97,  hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18, colour = 'black'),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
        legend.text = element_text(size=15),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=.5))+
  scale_shape_manual("", values=c("mean"=20,
                              "mean_range"=17))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100), limits = c(0, 100))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=Species,xend=Species, y=min,yend=max),inherit.aes=FALSE,
               linetype="longdash", color="black", size=0.55)+
  labs(x=NULL, y="Percentage of species-typical breeding units\nwith helpers in a population")+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5),"cm"))+
  draw_label("Birds", x = 2.1, y = 100, size = 20, fontface="bold")


p_birds

##Plot mammals

p_mammals<-
  ggplot(variance_mammals, aes(x=reorder(Species, order), precentage)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type), colour = 'black', size = 3, stroke = 1.5) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, angle = 70, colour = 'black',
                                   vjust = 0.97,  hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18, colour = 'black'),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
        legend.text = element_text(size=15),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=.5))+
  scale_shape_manual("", values=c("mean"=20,
                                  "mean_range"=17))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100), limits = c(0, 100))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=Species,xend=Species, y=min,yend=max),inherit.aes=FALSE,
               linetype="longdash", color="black", size=0.55)+
  labs(x=NULL, y="Percentage of species-typical breeding units\nwith helpers in a population")+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))+
  draw_label("Mammals", x = 2.9, y = 92, size = 20, fontface="bold")

p_mammals+
  draw_label("'", x = 14.3, y = -30.5, angle=70, size = 20, colour="black")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100), clip = "off")


#combining the two plots

combined_plot<-plot_grid(p_mammals+ theme(legend.position = 'none'),
                        p_birds+ theme(legend.position = 'none'),
                       align = "h", ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(5/10, 5/10))

combined_plot```

Thanks!

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOFn6.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf7In.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1s8V.jpg
````

Comment: check out this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427455/multiple-ggplots-of-different-sizes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple ggplots of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427455/multiple-ggplots-of-different-sizes)

Comment: you should really be making this plot by combining the datasets and using facetting to get the separate panels.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeSavva. that looks like an easy solution. BUT, I still want to have a separate x-axis for each plot. Right under each of them. Can I do that with faceting?

Comment: Thanks, @PedroAlencar. But it doesn't really make a difference. I still have the same problem even when using grid.arrange.

Comment: @YitzchakBen-Mocha yes use `facet_wrap` with the `scales="free_x"` option

Comment: Also, consider flipping the axes so that the discrete axis is vertical and the quant axis is horizontal. You will find it much easier to fit everything in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, adding this was the simplest solution:
ggsave("Figure 2.pdf", width = 40, height = 50, units = "cm")
Thanks for helping though!