# Arranging multiple ggplots with fixed aspect Ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have several Plots, all build out of facets of various numbers, but all with a fixed aspect ratio (See Picture). How can I combine all of them in one Plot, where the individual facets have the same size, while at the same time minimizing the unused space (here green).

[image]

I tried to do it with cowplot::plot_grid and fiddling with rel_hight, rel_width, and a filler Plot. Which kind of works, but is tedious and depends on the final image size (ggsave width). It feels like there must be a more robust and reliable way to achieve it?

```
#Combing the Plots
plot_grid(
          plot_grid(p1,p2, nrow = 2, rel_widths = c(1,1), labels = c("A","C")) ,
          plot_grid(p2,pN, nrow=2, rel_heights = c(1,0.45), labels=c("B","")),
          plot_grid(p3,p4,pN, nrow = 3, rel_heights = c(1.6,1,0.6), labels=c("D","E","")), 
          nrow = 1, rel_widths = c(1,1.4,0.65), labels = c("","B",""))
ggsave("example.png", width = 8, height = 5.35, bg="green")
```

Below is a minimal example to generate the data.

```
library(cowplot)

#Generate Test Data
counter <- 0
for (YAxis in paste(letters[1:4], "Axis")) {
    for (XAxis in paste(letters[1:4], "Axis")) {
        for (rows in c("A","B","C")) {
            for (col in c("A","B","C")) {
                counter <- counter + 1
                tmp <- data.frame(YAxis,XAxis,rows,col, value=rnorm(1)) 
                if (counter == 1) { df <- tmp              }
                if (counter != 1) { df <- rbind(df, tmp)              }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

#Plot Function
myPlotFnc <- function(subDF){
    p <- ggplot(subDF,aes(col,rows,fill= value))+
        geom_tile()+
        facet_grid(YAxis ~XAxis,switch="both")+
        coord_fixed()+ theme(legend.position = "none")
    return(p)
}

#filler plot
pN <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1,y=1), aes(x,y))+geom_blank()+ theme_void()


#generating Example Plots
p1 <- myPlotFnc(df[(df$YAxis == "a Axis"  & df$XAxis== "a Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "b Axis"  & df$XAxis== "b Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "a Axis"  & df$XAxis== "b Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "b Axis"  & df$XAxis== "a Axis"),]  )
p2 <- myPlotFnc(df[(df$YAxis == "a Axis"  & df$XAxis== "a Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "b Axis"  & df$XAxis== "b Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "a Axis"  & df$XAxis== "b Axis") |
                    (df$YAxis == "c Axis"  & df$XAxis== "c Axis") |
                    (df$YAxis == "c Axis"  & df$XAxis== "a Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "b Axis"  & df$XAxis== "a Axis"),]  )
p3 <- myPlotFnc(df[(df$YAxis == "a Axis"  & df$XAxis== "c Axis") |
                   (df$YAxis == "b Axis"  & df$XAxis== "c Axis"),]  )
p4 <- myPlotFnc(df[(df$YAxis == "d Axis"  & df$XAxis== "d Axis") ,]  )
```

Edit:
Adjusted rel. width sizes a bit more to get closer to the desired plot.

Comment: You could try  ggarrange() from library(ggpubr). Save the plots first in variables, then put them together with ggarrange().

Comment: I don't think this would change the behavior, since  ggarrange() is a wrapper for used plot_grid()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid.arrange` from `library(gridExtra)`, use `ncol` and `nrow` to specify how many plots by column or row and `widths` and `heights` for the plot sizes.

In your case, for example `grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)`

Comment: The problem with this direct approach is, that although all the plots are the same size, each tile would be different (e.g. Since-Sub figure B is bigger than E, the same plot size would result in smaller tile sizes in B)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, take a look to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427455/multiple-ggplots-of-different-sizes

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It definitely makes the grid layout easier to arrange, than what I did. However, in my case I am not aiming for a full grid layout. E.g. If I want the tiles to be the same everywhere B would always be on a different grid than all the other plots. 

I fiddled a bit more with the parameters to get closer to the desired plot (see Above). I hope this makes my goal clearer (remove the thin lines of green, while having identical tile sizes)