# Is there a way to turn a ggpairs() plot into a ggplot2 object?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggally

In a long but not complex analysis, I am generating a lot of `ggplot2` plots, which are being dealt in the same programmatic way.

I will also need matrix plots every now and then, but `ggplot2` no longer implements any matrix plot function (since `plotmatrix` is deprecated).

Like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735286/create-a-matrix-of-scatterplots-pairs-equivalent-in-ggplot2), GGally's `ggpairs()` implements matrix plot nicely.

The down side is that `ggpairs()` returns a ggplot2 object matrix instead of a single ggplot2 object, so I can no longer deal with it in the same fashion I was dealing until then.

Hence my question.  Is there a way to convert `ggpairs()`' return into a single ggplot2 object?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there's not. (Well, you could save it as an image, and plot that image on a new ggplot, but I guess that's not what you're looking for.)

Comment: If what you're looking for is a way to put a bunch of `ggplots` together then  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9490482/903061) along with [it's marked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7993722/903061) present quite a few options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @Gregor! I will read them.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731111/1870254)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a matrix of scatterplots (pairs() equivalent) in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735286/create-a-matrix-of-scatterplots-pairs-equivalent-in-ggplot2)