# Stack coefficient plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm running a set of models with the same independent variables but different dependent variables and would like to create a set of coefficient plots in one figures in which each model gets its own panel. The following code provides intuition but in this all of the models are integrated into one figure rather than have 3 unique panels side-by-side in one figure:

```
require("coefplot") 
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100), y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100), y3 = rnorm(100))
mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + z, data = dat)
mod2 <- lm(y2 ~ x + z, data = dat)
mod3 <- lm(y3 ~ x + z, data = dat)    
multiplot(mod1,mod2, mod3)
```

Which generates this plot:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to get them to panel next to each other in one figure? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your post to add the image from `multiplot(mod1, mod2, mod3)`?

Comment: Thanks; just incorporated the graph.

Comment: You could make searate plots and bind them together with `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Indeed, that might be the best way to go. Was curious whether there are any other standard functions that do multiple plots panel by panel.

Comment: You could try to make it work with facets. Or there are [several options like `grid.arrange` here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7993722/903061).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used the `coefplot` package before, but you can create a coefficient plot directly in `ggplot2`.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100), y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100), y3 = rnorm(100))
mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + z, data = dat)
mod2 <- lm(y2 ~ x + z, data = dat)
mod3 <- lm(y3 ~ x + z, data = dat)    

## Create data frame of model coefficients and standard errors
# Function to extract what we need
ce = function(model.obj) {
  extract = summary(get(model.obj))$coefficients[ ,1:2]
  return(data.frame(extract, vars=row.names(extract), model=model.obj))
}

# Run function on the three models and bind into single data frame
coefs = do.call(rbind, sapply(paste0("mod",1:3), ce, simplify=FALSE))

names(coefs)[2] = "se" 

# Faceted coefficient plot
ggplot(coefs, aes(vars, Estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2, lwd=1, colour="grey50") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Estimate - se, ymax=Estimate + se, colour=vars), 
                lwd=1, width=0) +
  geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=vars)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ model) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  labs(x="Coefficient", y="Value") +
  theme_grey(base_size=15)
```

[image]