# show multiple plots from ggplot on one page in r

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I want to make multiple ggplot in a loop and show them on one plot.

```
for ( i in 1:8) {
    g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=wt))+
        geom_point()
    print(g)
}
```

I want to arrange the plots above on one page, 4 rows and 2 columns. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `facet_grid` and/or `facet_wrap` functionality? Check this out https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Comment: Look at [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) or [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html) or [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork). If you're using a loop, you'll probably want to create a list with your plots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save all the plot in a `list` then use either `cowplot::plot_grid()` or `gridExtra::marrangeGrob()` to put them in one or more pages

See also:

- [Creating arbitrary panes in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/) (`patchwork`, `multipanelfigure` & `egg` packages)
- [Multiple plots in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/)

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create a list with a specific length 
plot_lst <- vector("list", length = 8)

for (i in 1:8) {
  g <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt)) +
    geom_point()
  plot_lst[[i]] <- g
}

# Combine all plots
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_lst, nrow = 4)
```

[image]

```r
library(gridExtra)
ml1 <- marrangeGrob(plot_lst, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
ml1
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in the loop you provided, the counter `i` isn't referenced in the plot, so you'll end up printing the same plot eight times!

If you have a bunch of different *subsets* of a single dataset and want to lay them out, you can follow @PKumar's comment and check out facetting in ggplot2. It essentially splits your data up into groups according to one or more of your columns and then lays them out in a [grid](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) or a [ribbon](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

On the other hand, if you have a bunch of a *different* plots that you want to combine on one page, there're a couple of packages that can make this happen:

- [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html#arranging-graphs-into-a-grid) is a fairly mature package that can do this, and
- [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) is a newer package that lets you lay plots out using arithmetic.

Hope those help!