# Adding the same component to a list of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of ggplot2 plots, and I want to add the same title (`Cars` to each element of the list

```
library(ggplot2)
 l <- list(
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, col = am)) + geom_point(),
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, col = am)) + geom_point(),
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, col = am)) + geom_point()
 )
```

Now I can refer to each element and add the title as follows

```
 l[[1]] + ggtitle("Cars")
 l[[2]] + ggtitle("Cars")
 l[[3]] + ggtitle("Cars")
```

But is there a way to add the title to all elements in the list at once?

(Note: For one layer, this is rather silly, but I can extend such an example to multiple layers.)

Comment: `lapply(l, \`+\`, ggtitle("Cars"))` or if adding multiple layers `lapply(l, function(x) x + ... + ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User H 1 answered the question. As **ggplot2** is different due to the layering, I was unsure if `lapply()` would work in this case. I now learned that the pipe symbol, `+` is a function to be applied over.

But adding a title and positioning the legend at the bottom has the desired effect:

```
 q <- lapply(l, function(x) x + ggtitle("Cars") + theme(legend.position = "bottom"))
 multiplot( plotlist = q, cols = 2)
```

where the code for `multiplot()` is found [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/).

[image]

Comment: FYI, there are several packages that can do a little bit more than `multiplot()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/786542